# Replacing a string in between using Chef and Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, chef-infra

I have a string that looks like this. Note the spaces in front. I wanted to replace this line that contains this string `>"${WLS_REDIRECT_LOG}"`.

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WLS_POLICY_FILE} ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}  >"${WLS_REDIRECT_LOG}" 2>&1
```

I just don't know if my regex is correct to match the line

```
mynewline = "TESTTTIIINGGG!!!"
ruby_block "Editing File" do
  block do
    fe = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("myFile.sh")
    fe.search_file_replace_line(/*>"${WLS_REDIRECT_LOG}"*/, mynewline)
    fe.write_file
  end
  #only_if { File.read("myFile.sh")
end
```

I am not that good in regex.

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localised guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need chef for that, plain old good ruby is fine:

```
corrected = File.read('myFile.sh')
corrected[/>"\$\{WLS_REDIRECT_LOG\}"/] = "TESTTTIIINGGG!!!"
File.write('myFile.sh', corrected)
```

More info: [`String#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

Comment: Doing that outside of a resource will have usually unexpected effects.

Answer (score 1):

FileEdit is an internal API within Chef and is not recommended for use by cookbook code. While you can use other Ruby code as mentioned in the other other answer, in general this kind of approach is very fragile. Creating a replacement that is fully convergent is often difficult, sometimes impossible. Check out cookbooks like `line` or `poise-file` for examples of a more refined API expressed as custom resources, but we recommend using fully convergent resources like `template` or `cookbook_file` whenever possible for this kind of thing.